# uncomplete AST using parser.prog.getTree()

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

hello there is my problem :

i wrote an antlr grammar that compiles and creates a good ast on antlr. Now i want to create some TDS and i have to explore my AST, i wrote a java code to do this, i've got no errors but my program returns only the first floor of the AST if some one could help me : there is my grammar :

```
grammar Grammaire;


options{

k=1;
output = AST;
}

tokens{
INIT;
CONDITION;
INC;
DEC_VAR;
DEC_CLASSE;
LISTE_ATTRIBUTS;
LISTE_PARAMETRES;
LISTE_PARAMETRES_EFFECTIFS;
DEC_ATTRIBUT;
DEC_METHOD;
PROGRAMME;
PARAMETRE;
BODY;
DO;
WRITE;
READ;
THIS;
NEW;
SUPER;
RETURN;
IF;
THEN;
ELSE;
DO;
FOR;
APPEL_MET;
BLOC;
}


prog :  (class_decl)* (var_decl)* (instruction)+ -> ^(PROGRAMME ^(class_decl)* ^(var_decl)* ^(instruction)*);


class_decl :    'class' IDF_CLASS ( 'inherit' IDF_CLASS )? '=' '{' class_item_decl '}' -> ^(DEC_CLASSE IDF_CLASS (IDF_CLASS)? class_item_decl );


class_item_decl :   (var_decl)* (method_decl)* -> ^(BODY ^(LISTE_ATTRIBUTS ^(var_decl)*)? ^(method_decl)*) ;


var_decl : 'var' IDF_METHOD ':' type ';' -> ^(DEC_VAR IDF_METHOD type);

type :  IDF_CLASS
        |'int'
        |'string'
        ;



method_decl :   'method' IDF_METHOD '(' method_args*')' (':' type)? '{' var_decl* instruction+ '}' -> ^(DEC_METHOD (type)? IDF_METHOD ^(LISTE_PARAMETRES (method_args)*)? ^(BODY var_decl* instruction+));




method_args :   IDF_METHOD ':' type (',' IDF_METHOD ':' type)* -> ^(PARAMETRE IDF_METHOD type)*;


instruction :   idf_method  
                |'if' expression 'then' instruction ('else' instruction)? 'fi' -> ^(IF expression ^(THEN instruction) ^(ELSE instruction)? )
                |'for' IDF_METHOD 'in' expression '..' expression 'do' instruction+ 'end'-> ^(FOR ^(CONDITION IDF_METHOD expression expression) ^(BODY (instruction)+))
                |'{' var_decl* instruction+ '}' -> ^(BLOC var_decl* instruction+)
                |'do' expression ';'-> ^(DO expression)
                |write
                |read
                |retour
                ;
idf_method  :   IDF_METHOD ':=' rule_garb  -> ^(':='IDF_METHOD rule_garb);

rule_garb 
    :   expression ';' -> expression
    |   'nil' ';'
    ;
write   : 'write' print -> ^(WRITE print)
    ;
print :  expression ';'-> expression
        ;

read    :   'read' IDF_METHOD ';' -> ^(READ IDF_METHOD);

retour  :   'return' '(' expression ')' ';' -> ^(RETURN expression) ;


expression :            'this' (test)? -> ^(THIS (test)?)
                |'super' (test)?  -> ^(SUPER (test)?)
                |'new' IDF_CLASS (test)? -> ^(NEW IDF_CLASS (test)?)
                |exprPlusMoins -> ^(exprPlusMoins)
                ;

exprPlusMoins : multexpr (('+' ^ | '-' ^)multexpr) * ;

multexpr : exprComp('*' ^ exprComp)* ;

exprComp : exprMoins (( '<' ^ | '>' ^ | '<=' ^ | '>=' ^ | '==' ^ | '!=' ^ ) exprMoins)?;

exprMoins 
    :   ('-' ^ )? atom;

atom :  IDF_METHOD(test)? -> ^(APPEL_MET IDF_METHOD (test)?)
    |CSTE_ENT
    |CSTE_BOOLEAN
    |CSTE_CHAINE
    |'(' expression ')'-> ^(expression)
    ;

test    :    '.'IDF_METHOD '(' expression? (',' expression)* ')' -> IDF_METHOD (^(LISTE_PARAMETRES_EFFECTIFS (expression)*))? ;

CSTE_BOOLEAN :  'TRUE'
        |'FALSE'
        ;
IDF_CLASS  :   ('A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')* ;
IDF_METHOD  :   ('a'..'z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')* ;
CSTE_ENT :   '0'..'9'+ ;
NEWLINE:('\r'? '\n') + {$channel=HIDDEN;};
WS  :   (' '|'\t')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
CSTE_CHAINE : '"' (.+) '"';
COMM    :   ('/*').*('*/'){$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

there is my code :

```
import java.io.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;


public class __Test__ {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String classPath =("/home/frozzen/compil/cholleyb1u/TEST/test2.txt");
        File code =new File(classPath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)code.length()];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(code));
        in.readFully(buffer);
        in.close();
        String retour = new String(buffer);

        GrammaireLexer Lex = new GrammaireLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(retour));
        GrammaireParser parser = new GrammaireParser(new CommonTokenStream(Lex));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(Lex);
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.prog().getTree();        
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree());        
    }
}
```

and there is the source code that i'm trying to get AST :

```
class Math =
{
    var param : int;
    method pow(a:int,b:int) :int
    {
        var retval : int;
        var i : int;
        if b == 0
        then
            return (1);
        fi

        retval :=1;
        for i in 1 .. b
        do
            retval := retval*a;
        end

        return (retval);
    }
}
var m : Math;
m:= new Math;
write m.pow(2,3);
```

Comment: Is this the *minimal* example? Where is the code that processes the AST?

Comment: first code is my grammar with the rewriting rules that creates ast on antlr, second code is the java code which should get this tree then the last code is the code that is going through my grammar. (sorry for my english i'm french)